# Index 0 is either negative or above rows count

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I keep receiving error message of "Index 0 is either negative or above rows count" on line that declares a specific row from SQL as the subject row. I've tried looking at other examples but I can't work out how to solve this specific problem. From my POV, SQL isn't an issue as everything is read correctly otherwise.

Code:

```
private Product GetSelectedProduct()
{
    DataView productsTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    productsTable.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductID = '{0}'", ddlProducts.SelectedValue);
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)productsTable[0];

    Product p = new Product();
    p.ProductID = row["ProductID"].ToString();
    p.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
    p.ShortDescription = row["ShortDescription"].ToString();
    p.LongDescription = row["LongDescription"].ToString();
    p.UnitPrice = (decimal)row["UnitPrice"];
    p.ImageFile = row["ImageFile"].ToString();
    return p;
}
```

Server Error:

> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 is either
>   negative or above rows count.

Stack Trace:

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 is either negative or above rows count.]
   System.Data.DataView.GetRow(Int32 index) +1788553
   System.Data.DataView.get_Item(Int32 recordIndex) +13
   Order.GetSelectedProduct() in f:\Year 2\Internet Applications Programming\Assignment 2\Lab 3 - 06-03-17\Ex04Cart\Order.aspx.cs:23
   Order.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\Year 2\Internet Applications Programming\Assignment 2\Lab 3 - 06-03-17\Ex04Cart\Order.aspx.cs:12
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2952
```

Comment: `productsTable` contains nothing. so `productsTable[0]` is out of range.

Answer (score 1):

`productsTable` contains nothing. so `productsTable[0]` is out of range.

So let's check after the filtering if we have any records.

```
private Product GetSelectedProduct()
{
    DataView productsTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    productsTable.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductID = '{0}'", ddlProducts.SelectedValue);

    if (productsTable.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)productsTable[0];

        Product p = new Product();
        p.ProductID = row["ProductID"].ToString();
        p.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
        p.ShortDescription = row["ShortDescription"].ToString();
        p.LongDescription = row["LongDescription"].ToString();
        p.UnitPrice = (decimal)row["UnitPrice"];
        p.ImageFile = row["ImageFile"].ToString();
        return p;
    }
    else
    {
        // Or throw an exception, if your logic dictates that this method SHOULD return a record.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster, gotcha